# Printing an array shows symbols instead of characters C++

Tags: c++, arrays, symbols

Hey I am having problems learning arrays in C++.

The program I have to develop is a simple array that reads in a name (in char) and prints it after input.

My program reads it in but outputs it in symbols, not in characters? 
Can somebody explain me what I am doing wrong?

```
Char name[10];
cout <<"Give a name: "; 
cin >> name[10];
cout << endl;

for (int i=0; i<strlen(name);i++)
{
cout << name[i];
}
```

Can somebody explain where in my code it goes wrong and puts it out in symbols and not the normal characters that I gave in?

Comment: You are actually passing an array or rather a pointer to cin function. cin expects a string, int or float variable type and not an array. when you pass name[10] to cin, it only interpret the array name[10] as name[0]. So you are actually passing char at index [0] and not the entire array. Why not use a string and forget about the for loop.

Comment: @Juniar: Nonsense, mostly. He's passing a single char, not the whole array. And the compiler does not interpret `name[10]` as `name[0]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This

```
cin >> name[10];
```

reads only one character into `name[10]`. The beginning of the array remains uninitialized, it contains garbage, which is what you see as "symbols". And `name[10]` is actually out of bounds for your array.

To read a C-style string into a `char` array, you should do

```
cin >> name;
```

But you'd be much better off not using raw arrays for storing strings, especially when you have to deal with user input of unpredictable length. Learn to use `std::string` instead.

Comment: Wow, how simple was that, thank you very much. But I don't understand the principe of that. If I declared an array, shouldn't I put the character's that i'm giving in, IN TO, that array? Could you give me more information about this please?

Comment: You told the compiler to read into array slot #11 (remember that arrays are zero based, so 10 is the 11th slot).  The type of the 11th slot is `char`.  Thus the compiler used the function for reading in **a single character**, which is what you told it to do.  AndreyT is showing you how to read in an array of char.

Comment: Thank you very much Thomas for your reply. I think I finally got it! I already reviewed the method of using strings and it's much easier, too bad my teacher doesn't allow it yet :).

Comment: @Kahn Kah: If you want to read a string, you have to give `cin` a *pointer* to the beginning of a character sequence, into which your data should be read. So, if you want to read it into `name`, starting from the very beginning of `name`, you have to give it a pointer to `name[0]`. `cin >> &name[0]` will do what you want. But in this context `&name[0]` can be expressed as mere `name`, which is why `cin >> name` works as well.

Comment: you can also look at `cin.getline( name, 10 )` which will keep input from overrunning at [8], and give you a null terminator at [9] so you can `cout << name`. in this way you can 'forget about the loop' as others have mentioned.
In any case, it's good to understand arrays at this level, which can be used for other types as well

Comment: To add data into an array or to use an array to store data, You will need to use a for loop or while loop. Elements are added to an array one at a time using a loop, which iterates from array`s index = 0 to array`s index = array.length -1, the last position. cin does not know anything about array, and if you want to use an array as an input stream data receiver. Then you have to call cin 10 times within a loop while adding one character at a time.

Comment: @Juniar: And nonsense here as well. There is an overload of `operator<<` which takes a `char*`, which reads one whitespace delimited group of characters, and stores it as a null-terminated c-string. It's not a good idea to use (as AndreyT suggests), but it still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing C++, just use `std::string`.

```
std::string name;
cout << "Give a name: ";
cin >> name;
cout << name;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply but we don't learn the chapter of strings until object orientated programming in C++, that's why I was using characters. However I still didn't understand why my /cin/ didn't work and my code /couts/ in symbols. I would really want to understand this chapter fully.